# Number of possible passwords given some condition

Tags: combinatorics

> A password is four or five characters long, where each character is from $\{a,b,...,z,0,...,9,@,\#\}$. How many possible passwords are there that contain at least one digit?

In total, we have $38$ characters, so, using the inclusion-exclusion principle, we get $P=(38^5-28^5)+(38^4-28^4)=63495280$. The answer, however, is $19174512$, but I don't see how my reasoning is wrong.

Any hints please?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your reasoning.  Are there extra conditions on the passwords that you may have missed?

Comment: Nope, that's all. @RobertShore